# Where does qmake look for pri files?

Tags: qt, qmake

I have the following setup (using qt 5.6.1-1):

```
qtbase/bin
...
qtbase/mkspecs
...
qtdeclarative/mkspecs
```

When trying to build qtquickcontrols I get the following error:

```
qmake
make
Some of the required modules (qtHaveModule(quick)) are not available.
Skipped.
```

I think it's because qmake is only looking for .pri files in qtbase/mkspecs. Is there an environment variable to set the mkspecs
search path?

I tried setting QMAKESPEC, QT_PLUGIN_PATH and INCLUDEPATH, but couldn't get past the error message.

Build process:

```
tar -xf qtbase-opensource-src-5.6.1.tar.xz && cd
./configure -prefix=qtbase/prefix
make
make install

tar -xf qtdeclarative-opensource-src-5.6.1.tar.xz && cd
qmake PREFIX=qtdeclarative/prefix
make install
```

fails with write error to qtbase/prefix (it's not writeable by the build user)

```
sed -i s#INSTALL_ROOT)/qtbase/prefix#INSTALL_ROOT)/qtdeclarative/prefix
make install

tar -xf qtquickcontrols-opensource-src-5.6.1.tar.xz && cd
qmake PREFIX=qtquickcontrols/prefix
make install
```

fails with
Some of the required modules (qtHaveModule(quick)) are not available.
Skipped.

Comment: Your life will be much simpler by getting the complete source and building everything. You then don't need to worry about anything, it just works. You also shouldn't be building in the source folder. For any version of Qt, you'll have at least 3 folders: source, build and install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a properly set up Qt installation, it won't be a problem. Make sure that:

1. You've compiled all the modules.
2. You haven't moved your Qt build: it has hardcoded paths and can't be moved once built.

You should also prefer to build Qt in its own build folder, if you aren't doing it already.

Comment: I built qtbase and qtdeclarative using qmake PREFIX=/absolute/path/to/dir && make install and haven't moved them. But when building qtdeclarative I have paths $(INSTALL_ROOT)/qtbase/prefix instead of $(INSTALL_ROOT)/qtdeclarative/prefix. I replaced the $(INSTALL_ROOT)/qtbase/prefix with the qtdeclarative/prefix before running make install. Could this be the problem? What is the correct way to pass the prefixes?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. Run configure in the build directory, with install prefix given to configure (not through env. variables!). Then build the modules you wish, then install them. You should do a parallel build to speed it up, and these builds fail if you do `make install` straight away, you should do `make -j && make -j install`.

Comment: Running qmake doesn't generate a ./configure file. And there isn't one in the tarball https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.1-1/submodules/qtdeclarative-opensource-src-5.6.1-1.tar.xz What am I missing?

Comment: You need a full source tarball, and you don't build Qt using qmake at first. Before that you need `configure` to build qmake for you! You're doing something very wrong, please edit your exact steps (starting from a clean system with dev tools installed) into the question.

Comment: so I updated the steps I took. I managed to build other qt modules, but I think they don't make use of the qtHaveModule macro. Also building packages that depend on qt and use cmake work too after NO_DEFAULT_PATH is removed from the qtbase cmake files, I managed to build all of kde frameworks tier 1 and 2 (which depends heavily on qt)

Comment: "Adding" packages to a distro's Qt is a fool's errand. You either want to modify the distro's package script (e.g. srpm) to build the packages you want, or you want a fresh Qt build. Qt is designed so that several versions can coexist, you select a Qt version for a particular build by passing its install path to cmake, or by calling its qmake explicitly to set up a build (e.g. `/opt/local/myqt/bin/qmake`).

Comment: I thought that the modular qt was supposed to be able to find qt modules through env variables? But in any case thank you. I've looked at how arch linux, linux from scratch and nixos do it, but I haven't yet figured out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You don't need to set any environment variables to use Qt for development. The modules are added to a common location when Qt is being installed to a given prefix. **All modules belong in the same prefix!** You'll see this in action when you get the **complete** tarball with all modules and configure/make/make install them. The folder structure in the prefix will be created for you. There will be only one prefix.